# What's the c++ version of this java map code

Tags: java, c++, dictionary

What would the same code in c++ look like, or the closest thing to it?

```
public class Skill{

     public Skill(String name){

     }

     public static Map<String, Skill> getSkills(){
          Map<String, Skill> skills = new Map<String, Skill>();
          skills.add("Endurance", new Skill());
          return skills;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this link contains all information. :)
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/

Comment: When you Google "c++ map", what didn't you understand about the page full of valid results? We can't help you unless we understand why you're not able to derive / understand the answer on your own, and surely you have already done such a search before asking others for help.

Comment: I've tried multiple times in c++ but I keep getting syntax errors. I cant find anything that deals with the 'value' being a class that i have made.

Comment: @user2103959 if you've tried in C++, you need to include what you've tried in your question -- that gives people a basis to start from that you can more easily grasp.

Comment: Ill definitely remember that for next time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::map<std::string,Skill*> skills;
skills["Endurance"] = new Skill();
```

Comment: So they are pointers to the skill?

Comment: They can be even not pointers, but in that case while adding an element to the map. you would insert inside it a copy of it built using copy constructor (if defined). Btw, I answered to you just to put you in the right direction since you are a new user. The policy of SO sugggest not to answer to a so generic question. In your next question, please try to provide a less generic question and tell us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Well in that case thanks so much. And yes, my next question will be improved!